# Sending mails using external server in media temple

Tags: smtp

I am working on a site whose server is hosted at media temple (gs), and my domain is hosted at Godaddy. I have taken an external server at postmarkapp.com to send only emails. Can anyone please help me out with what are the changes do i need to make in my setting to send mails. 
Some of the things which I have tried are:
Changed my user name and password to API token given to me by Postmark
disable sending mails from my mt server
tried both with port 25 and 2525

Please help..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natalie,

JP here from the Postmark team. Do you have SMTP enabled for your Postmark account? If you look under the Credentials tab on your Virtual Server Rack you'll see a setting to enable SMTP. If that's already enabled, what error are you getting?

You can email support@postmarkapp.com as well if you're still having difficulty.

Cheers!  -JP

Comment: Asking the support help desk should always be the first stop :-)